# In android version 2.3.6 web view not show content which have image

Tags: android, android-websettings

My Response is the form of html data,which contain  string data and image,when i load the content in web view then it show proper result on the android versions 3.0 but it give me error on android version 2.3.

error is:
01-06 14:54:18.735: D/test(32652): error code:-12
01-06 14:54:18.735: D/test(32652): discrip:The page could not be opened because the URL is invalid.

Here is my Code:

```
 mWebViewFirst.loadData(setterHtmlScreenList.get(0).getScreenText(),
                          "text/html","ISO-8859-1" );
 mWebViewFirst.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebViewFirst.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
 mWebViewFirst.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
   @Override
      public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,Sring description, String failingUrl) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             Log.d("test","error code:"+errorCode);
             Log.d("test","discrip:"+description);

              super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);




                            }
                        });
```

Please Help Me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: where the URL or file?

Comment: i have string which is in the form of html.

Comment: in your asset folder?

Comment: i store it in string object ,the data is getting from the webservice.

Comment: It's not clear for me, if you have used HTML file then you have to place this HTML file in asset folder and give the path of this file or use URL of a webservice .

Comment: if my answer will help you then I will post this answer. so please let me know.